# Is it safe to run a local http server?

Tags: apache, security, networking

I am doing web development and running, say, Apache, just to test things locally on my machine. Say, I have a web application that allows one to view or edit many files on my computer. What should I do to make sure that nobody can access this server remotely?

Run the server under a dedicated account? Simply not set the root directory to "/"? Simply check the server's settings and make sure that only local IPs are allowed? Or is it already guaranteed by my router (if I am using Wifi at home)? What about using public Wifi?

Answer (score 1):

You can just simply block any network traffic except loopback (localhost) on Apache port using firewall in your OS.

I simply block all traffic from any local network addresses, which are:

- 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255
- 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255
- 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255

You should also take into consideration IPv6 addresses.

Another thing you can try is switching:

```
Order allow,deny
```

To:

```
Order deny,allow
```

In your site's settings file (I guess it will be *sites-enabled/000-default*).

Comment: So every time I decide to run some kind of server, the first step should be figuring out how to block any network traffic except loopback, correct? What if I am running a development server built into some framework, e.g. django? Is it safe?

Comment: If you block any traffic outside the local computer then it shouldn't be unsafe.

Comment: I mean, whenever I install a new framework or a new server, should I be concerned with first of all finding out how to block all traffic in it? Or can I block it for all frameworks/servers? For now I placed my Mac Firewall in the most restrictive mode, but I guess, there should be other solutions...

Comment: It depends of how you set block. If you block traffic via firewall (method #1) then you shouldn't be concerned about it, till it's all on the same port. If you pick second method, traffic will be blocked only on 1 site *profile* in your apache. :)